# for-each loop not fetching all elements in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have written list of mapping elements in a template and I'm using for each loop with call-template. But I'm not getting all elements. Here is the below example:

```
    <stores>
  <store>
    <books>
      <book>
        <section>1</section>
        <bookinfo>
          <bookdetails>
            <A>Author</A>
            <B>Dreams</B>
          </bookdetails>
        </bookinfo>
      </book>
     </books>
     <books>
      <book>
        <section>2</section>
        <bookinfo>
          <bookdetails>
            <A>Author</A>
            <B>Dreams</B>
        </bookdetails>
       </bookinfo>
      </book>
    </books>
  </store>
</stores>
```

In my xslt I'm writing like this:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
 <StoreDetails>           
   <xsl:for-each select="//stores/store/books/book">     
       <xsl:call-template name="name">
            <xsl:with-param name="param" select="."/> 
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:for-each>
            
     </StoreDetails>
```

But this is not working. If I give like `<xsl:for-each select="//store/books/bookinfo">`  then it's working but the element `<section>1</section>` is missing in the output. I want all the elements under element`<book>`.

Here is my expected output:

```
<LocalStore>
     <LocalDetails>
     <section>1</section>
      <BookType>Author</BookType>
       <BookLPP>Dreams</BookLPP>
     </LocalDetails>
     <LocalDetails>
     <section>2</section>
      <BookType>Author1</BookType>
       <BookLPP>Dreams1</BookLPP>
     </LocalDetails>
      </LocalStore>
```

I should use templates and variables as per my existing requirement. Here is the clear link of sample:
https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3MP42NC/2

Comment: where is the expected output? from the xsl fragment it is not clear what is the use of template "name"?

Comment: I'm mapping all elements under <xsl:template name="name"> and now calling that template. I'm getting multiple repetitive tags called <bookinfo>. I want to fetch by iterating inside document to fetch every element under <book>.

Comment: Show the code of that template you call,plus the output you want and the one you get.

Comment: I have shared the link now Martin. Please check.

Comment: The problem you report is not reproducible using the **partial** code you have posted. Please post a [mcve] with all the necessary code **within your question**.

Comment: Hi Michael,Here is the link of my original code. for-each is not working as expected. I want <locationNumber></locationNumber> tag to be populated in the output. https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bET2rXG/6

Comment: @Pinky I have answered your question. Next time , please save us time and post all the code necessary to reproduce the problem within the question.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your XML is not well formed.  When a parent element has a child element, the closing tag for the child element needs to be before the closing element of the parent element.  So that the entire child element is within the parent element.  See the example below.

```
<stores>
  <store>
    <books>
      <book>
        <section>1</section>
        <bookinfo>
          <bookdetails>
            <A>Author</A>
            <B>Dreams</B>
          </bookdetails>
        </bookinfo>
      </book>
     </books>
     <books>
      <book>
        <section>2</section>
        <bookinfo>
          <bookdetails>
            <A>Author</A>
            <B>Dreams</B>
        </bookdetails>
       </bookinfo>
      </book>
    </books>
  </store>
</stores>
```

Comment: Sorry for giving improper sample request here. But my issue is not solved yet.

Comment: No problem.  I suggest fixing your sample so that it is well formed.  That will help other people help you.  Cheers!

Comment: Also your  <xsl:template match="/> needs to be  <xsl:template match="/">.  That should get you going.

Answer (score 0):

The problem (at least the main problem) is with the code you have omitted from your question.

When you call a named template, the context does not change. In this case the context is established by your instruction:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//stores/store/books/book">
```

From this context, the instruction:

```
<xsl:variable name="A" select="books//bookinfo/bookdetails/A"/>
```

does not select anything because `books` is not a child of `book`. It should be something like:

```
<xsl:variable name="A" select=".//bookinfo/bookdetails/A"/>
```

Likewise for your other variable.

---

See the corrected demo: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3MP42NC/4

Comment: But <section>1</section>..this tag is not iterating. I have mentioned this is the issue in my question.

Comment: To get the `section` from the context of `book`, you can use simply `<xsl:value-of select="section"/>`. If you are in the context of `bookdetails` then use `<xsl:value-of select="../../section"/>`. -- P.S. I have only now noticed that the input you have posted here is different from the input in the demo. So now we are discussing three different scenarios at the same time. This is not how it's supposed to be.

Comment: Sorry. I'm new to this site. there were multiple bookinfo details under section 1 and section 2. I need to get output under <section>1</section> tag <bookinf>details1</bookinfo>details2<bookinfo>. But I'm getting section1 for details1, again section1 for details 2.